# Invalid geometries

Tags: shapefile, vector, geometry, spatialite, invalid-data

I have downloaded the latest spatialite-gui v.1.4.0.  (spatialite version 2.4.0.)
When I try to correct invalid geometries and I use the following string (that I use to use with the past version):

`UPDATE com2011 SET geometry = ST_MakeValid(geometry)
    WHERE ST_IsValid(geometry) = 0;`

This string does not work at all!  It seems that ST_MakeValid(geometry) is a command that is not working anymore!

How can I remedy this problem or can you tell me the new string?

Comment: ST_IsValid(geometry) returns boolean, not a number. should be ST_IsValid(geometry) = 'f'

Comment: How does the "string not work at all"?  Please edit the question and include what error you are getting or what the result is.

Comment: @sharonbn, ST_IsValid is documented to return -1, 0, or 1 in https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html.

Comment: for ktti
the error signal is:
SQL ERROR: unrecognized error  “ɕ”

Answer (score 1):

You can do a controlled test for checking if ST_MakeValid is working or not. For example with this polygon that has a self-intersection:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
ST_MakeValid(
ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 300 580, 480 580, 300 400, 460 400, 300 580 ))')));
```

The result should be a multipolygon

```
MULTIPOLYGON(((384.705882 484.705882, 460 400, 300 400, 384.705882 484.705882)), ((300 580, 480 580, 384.705882 484.705882, 300 580)))
```